# Layered navigation: intval on price filter

Tags: price, layered-navigation, filter, rounding

I can see `$prices = array_map('floatval', $prices);` in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`.

I was wondering if I could `intval` without creating my own block, etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event dispatched in the methods that use `floatval` (`loadPrices`, `loadPreviousPrices`, `loadNextPrices`) so you have to create your own model that rewrites these methods. All you need is a single model (so no blocks)

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price 
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price {
    public function loadPrices($limit, $offset = null, $lowerPrice = null, $upperPrice = null) {
        $prices = parent::loadPrices($limit, $offset, $lowerPrice, $upperPrice);
        if ($prices) {
            $prices = array_map('intval', $prices);
        }
        return $prices;
    } 
    //do the same for loadPreviousPrices and loadNextPrices
}
```

Comment: I still didn't get the `config.xml` rewrite to work. weird. I'll keep trying variations... ;-)